# AMQP/RabbitMQ-Server/EventMachine with PhusionPassenger/Rails Can Only Receive the First Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, passenger, amqp, eventmachine

I'm using AMQP / RabbitMQ for my Ruby on Rails app.

I put the following amqp.rb file under config/initializers: (Copied and changed from a Recipe: http://www.hiringthing.com/2011/11/04/eventmachine-with-rails.html#sthash.iqCWUtOn.dpbs)

```
require 'amqp'

# References:
#   1. Getting Started with AMQP and Ruby
#      http://rubyamqp.info/articles/getting_started/
#   2. EventMachine and Rails
#      http://www.hiringthing.com/2011/11/04/eventmachine-with-rails.html#sthash.iqCWUtOn.dpbs
#   3. Connecting to the broker, integrating with Ruby on Rails, Merb and Sinatra
#      http://rubyamqp.info/articles/connecting_to_broker/
module AppEventMachine
  def self.start
    if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
      Rails.logger.info "###############################################################################"
      Rails.logger.info "Running EventMachine/Rails with PhusionPassenger ......"
      Rails.logger.info "###############################################################################"
      PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
      # =>  for passenger, we need to avoid orphaned threads
        if forked && EventMachine.reactor_running?
          EventMachine.stop
        end

        spawn_eventmachine_thread
        die_gracefully_on_signal
      end
    else
      Rails.logger.info "###############################################################################"
      Rails.logger.info "PhusionPassenger is not running.  Probably you are running Rails locally ......"
      Rails.logger.info "###############################################################################"

      # faciliates debugging
      Thread.abort_on_exception = true
      # just spawn a thread and start it up
      spawn_eventmachine_thread unless defined?(Thin)
      # Thin is built on EventMachine, doesn't need this thread
    end
  end

  def self.spawn_eventmachine_thread
    Thread.new {
      EventMachine.run do
        AMQP.channel ||= AMQP::Channel.new(AMQP.connect(:host => '127.0.0.1')) # Q_SERVER, :user=> Q_USER, :pass => Q_PASS, :vhost => Q_VHOST ))
        AMQP.channel.on_error(&method(:handle_channel_exception))
        AMQP.channel.queue(MixpanelJob::QUEUE_NAME, :exclusive => true)
                    .subscribe { |metadata, payload| MixpanelJob::handle_sending(metadata, payload) }
      end
    }
  end

  def self.handle_channel_exception(channel, channel_close)
    Rails.logger.error "###############################################################################"
    Rails.logger.error "Oops... a channel-level exception: code = #{channel_close.reply_code}, message = #{channel_close.reply_text}"
    Rails.logger.error "###############################################################################"
  end

  def self.die_gracefully_on_signal
    Signal.trap("INT") {
      Rails.logger.error "###############################################################################"
      Rails.logger.error "Stopping the EventMachine ......"
      EventMachine.stop
      Rails.logger.error "###############################################################################"
    }
    Signal.trap("TERM") {
      Rails.logger.error "###############################################################################"
      Rails.logger.error "Stopping the EventMachine ......"
      EventMachine.stop
      Rails.logger.error "###############################################################################"
    }
  end
end

AppEventMachine.start
```

After I start Rails with PhusionPassenger, I saw that it's running with PhusionPassenger, and then I try to send messages to the queue, but to my surprise:

```
.subscribe { |metadata, payload| MixpanelJob::handle_sending(metadata, payload) }
```

The `subscribe` handler was only executed once, i.e., only the first message is received, any other messages (2nd, 3rd), the `subscribe` handler never gets called.

Comment: This might happen if your job fails. Try replacing MixpanelJob::handle_sending(metadata, payload) with "puts payload" and see if it works then

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right.  It seems my `MixpanelJob::handle_sending` failed.  I need to handle that. Hmmm, it's weird that `Mixpanel` never throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joshua's comment.  It turns out that `MixpanelJob::handl_sending` failed, and it's blocking the EventMachine thread.